# Viewing files from a corrupted Windows hard drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ntfs, disk-management, data-corruption

I apologize if I sound really nooby ahead of time; this hard drive is giving me so many problems...

So, it's a windows laptop hard drive that has the notorious "Blue screen of death," I can install another Windows OS on it just fine, but I need to get personal information and pictures off of the drive prior to resetting it.

I have a docking station that I connect the drive to, go to "Disks," select the disk, and the partitions look like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Pa6.jpg) with it saying it has all that "free space" that is actually files, after some time, it looks like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiFyA.jpg) with it having "unknown" which is supposed to be NTFS, then several minutes later the drive acts like it was disconnected and disappears for a couple minutes prior to restarting that whole process.
(Side note: sometimes it does stay at having the partitions as "unknown" for a good while)

After hours and hours of repeating this, there has been some times for reasons completely unknown to me the partitions look like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXAOM.jpg) with it being exactly how it should be. It's done this about three times, the first time it was loading files really slow but I managed to get to my user files and saw them, then the drive acted like it was disconnected and disappeared. The other two times it acted like it was disconnected while the file system was still mounting.

Another side note: I tried just viewing the files on my windows PC and laptop first, but every time I tried to open file explorer the computer would just freeze until I unplugged the docking station.

Can someone please help me understand what is happening or how I can go about getting my files back prior to resetting it?

Comment: So you've got a windows problem... Where does ubuntu come in? Did you start an ubuntu to get your files rescued? (Iooks like it from the screenshots, but haven't mentioned it in any way in your text).

Comment: You seem to be on the right path, but it sounds like the hard drive is dying/dead.  As long as the drive/partition is not encrypted, you should be able to mount and view all of the files on the drive as well as copy to them to another mounted device.

Comment: Kanehekili; It's a windows 10 hard drive as I stated, and I tried just viewing the files on a working windows computer (As the "another side note" explains), but that didn't work, so I tried booting up Ubuntu and seeing if it crashed my computer on there and I was at least able to get further on Ubuntu.

Comment: Nmath; Yes, very likely that's the case... it's not encrypted. So, do you think if I reinstall Windows on the drive it would just get corrupted and be unusable again?